# How to access insert statement values in before insert trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to write a trigger that will be fired before insert in the table and will check for the range of a particular column. Here is the code that i have

```
create or replace TRIGGER
ABC_BI_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON 
TEMP_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    maxUID number;
    abcUID number;
BEGIN
    maxUID := 1500;
    select new.ABC_UID into mslUID from dual;
    if mslUID < maxUID THEN
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'NO values available: contact RE');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

The way i have used new.ABC_UID is not working and i am new to this. new.ABC_UID is the value passed in the insert statement for the column ABC_UID.
Help me if you have any other alternative for this problem or if you can correct me in this code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `select` it's not needed:

```
maxUID := 1500;
if :new.ABC_UID < maxUID THEN
    raise_application_error (-20001, 'NO values available: contact RE');
END IF;
```

If you do want that in a variable, because you need that elsewhere:

```
maxUID := 1500;
mslUID := :new.ABC_UID;

if mslUID < maxUID THEN
    raise_application_error (-20001, 'NO values available: contact RE');
END IF;
```

Comment: getting this error `PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.ABC_UID' must be declared` while using new.ABC_UID

Comment: @anurag: ah sorry, forgot the `:`  (see my edit) - too much Postgres programming

Comment: it is been created, but the way i am handling the max value of that column would work.

Comment: @anurag..the way you are doing will never work until you make 2 changes..1) declare a varibale named "mslUID" and putting semicolon ahead of new. Like :new.ABC_UID. And ofcourse that's not the most elegant way of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going to throw errors. See reasons below why? And the working version of your code, if you want to go with yours else choose solution by @Horse.

```
Create or replace TRIGGER ABC_BI_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON TEMP_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    maxUID number;
    abcUID number;  ---Redundant
    mslUID number;  ---Not declared in your code.

BEGIN
    maxUID := 1500;

    mslUID := :new.ABC_UID; --abc_uid is the column of table Temp_table         

    If mslUID < maxUID THEN
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'NO values available: contact RE');
    END IF;
END;
/
```